# New Liferay project- there is no such an option

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

I want to create new liferay project but there is no option "Create new Liferay Project" in Eclipse IDE, there is only either "New Liferay Plugin Project" or "New Liferay Project from Existing Source" can somebody tell me why there is no possibility to create new Liferay project ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjp7J.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect from a "Liferay Project" that's not a "Liferay Plugin Project"?

This is just a naming glitch on both command's titles - in fact, *both* commands denote "Plugin Projects" for Liferay, despite the different names.

When you create a new plugin project, you get a chance to define the plugin type in a wizard dialog. When you import a (plugin) project, the plugin type is derived from the actual project's content.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When you install liferay in your eclipse . then u can switch to liferay workspace .
Now Go to File --> New ---> Liferay Project .

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I know it but i do not have "Create New Project" ;/

New Project ->>

[image]

Comment: Please don't answer to your own question with more details (unless it's an actual answer): Rather edit your question and provide more details there.

Comment: OK, sorry, it was last time ;-)

Comment: in order to make this question more readable: You can still do so: Please edit your question, delete your answer. Note, I've already answered already, but questions are typically read long time after they've initially been answered, so it's good to leave them in the best accessible state.